# Why is the linear span of finitely many random variables automatically closed in $L^2$?

Tags: integration, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1, \ldots X_n$ be real-valued random variables in $L^2$. Consider the span 
$$
U = \text{span}(X_1, \ldots X_n) = \bigg\{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_j X_j \colon \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{R} \bigg\}.
$$
Why is $U$ automatically closed in $L^2$?

Comment: If $Y_n\in U$ is convergent in $L^2$, and $a_1,..., a_m$ $m\leq n$ is an orthonormal basis of $U$. Then for each fixed $i=1,...,m$, $(Y_n,a_i)$ is convergent. In fact $|(Y_r,a_i)-(Y_s,a_i)|\leq |Y_r-Y_s||a_i|$ by Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: A finite dimensional subspace of every topological vector space (over a complete field) is closed.

Comment: If you have already learned some functional analysis, you might know the following theorem: In any topological vector space, a finite dimensional subspace is always closed.

Comment: If one of the answers below has helped you, you can accept it using the green tick beside the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Let $(Z_p) \in U^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a converge sequence such that $Z_p = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_{j,p} X_j$. Since $(Z_p)$ is a Cauchy sequence then for every $j$, $(\lambda_{j,p})_p$ is a Cauchy sequence, and it converges to some $\lambda_j$. Let $Z = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j X_j$By triangle inequality $||Z_p - Z||_2 \le \sum_{j=1}^n||X_j||_2 |\lambda_{p,j}-\lambda_j| {\rightarrow}_{p \rightarrow \infty} 0$.

Conclusion : the limit of $(Z_p)$ is $Z$.

Comment: It is not true in general that each sequence $(\lambda_{j, p} )_p $ is Cauchy. For this to be true, the $X_j $ would need to be linearly independent.

Comment: I implicitly suppose $X_j$ linearly independent because otherwise it would the same with smaller $n$.